# STAssertEquals NSTimeIntervals

Tags: cocoa, ocunit

I'm write unit test cases for my cocoa class. Below is the test case. I can't figure out why this test case fails, even though the `expect` and `diff` in the assert message are the same. I suspect it may have something to do with how double or NSTimeInterval is calculated

`NSTimeInterval day = 60*60*24;`

```
NSDate * current = [NSDate date];

NSDate * daysAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-6*day sinceDate:current];

NSTimeInterval diff = [current timeIntervalSinceDate:daysAgo];

NSTimeInterval expect = 6 * day;

STAssertEquals(expect, diff, @"Failed expecting: %ld, getting %ld", expect, diff);
```

Comment: I tried your code and this test passes. Did you write it in the question box? If so, please show your actual code that fails. What architecture are you building for/testing on?

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing `NSTimeIntervals`, which are typedef'ed to `double`. Read e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/ (or http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to find out why you cannot use exact comparisons for float/double computations. You should always compare intervals, e.g. by using

`STAssertEqualsWithAccuracy(expect, diff, 0.001, @"Failed expecting: %ld, getting %ld", expect, diff);`

Comment: Also, both in the original code and in your revised version, `%ld` is the wrong formatter; it would be correct for a `long int`, but is incorrect for a `double` (or `NSTimeInterval`). I'd expect to see garbage values in the output. The correct formatter is `%f`.